# What does the $ in drive mappings and AD objects mean?

Tags: windows, path

At my workplace, some objects in AD and some drive mappings in network have $ sign as part of their path/name/identifier.

For example a security group "$Sales" and "SQLServer2005MSFTEUser$servername$MSSQLSERVER"; or if I key in "Y:" in the windows explorer address bar, it brings up "D$ (\\servername) (Y:)"

Is there any significance of the $ symbol? A naming convention? windows pathname feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a folder or drive is shared with a $ at the end of the name, it is a "hidden" or "admin" share that is not displayed if you go to `\\servername\`. You would have to type in the full path manuall, such as `\\server\c$`. Each drive on a Windows machine has is shared by default (along with IPC and admin) but can only be accessed my admin accounts.

I haven't seen a $ in front of a group before so I am unable to help with that.

Comment: The $ in the group name is probably just a local convention invented by the OP's IT folk.

Comment: @tombull89 I edited the AD object name for clarification. Even the SQL created group has $ in it.

Comment: @tombull89 is the $ automatically appended to the name by the system or can I manually rename my drive name and it will magically become "hidden" or "admin"?

Comment: @Jake You have to append the $ yourself when you share the folder or drive.

Comment: @Jake: in the case of the SQL group, the $ is just being used to separate the different parts of the name for readability.  It has no particular significance.